# JIRA JQL to get all cross team dependent tickets

Tags: jira, jql

I am trying to make a saved Issues filter so that I can quickly find all of my Team's tickets that have a relation to a ticket from another Team.

I have mocked up some pseudo SQL to explain what I am trying to do in JQL. I just can't seem to figure out how to JOIN in JQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Tickets] AS A
INNER JOIN [Tickets] AS B ON A.Relatesto = B.ID
WHERE A.Team <> B.Team
AND A.Status <> 'Resolved'
```

Comment: Could you possibly provide a less SQL specific description? I'm not familiar with SQL but quite familiar with JQL and so may be able to provide an answer if I can understand the question better.

Comment: I've somewhat understood your question but please do try to be clear next time around. So in situations like this what I recommend my teams to do use a single label. Create a label -  "Team A" or the exact name of your team. Once you have done that ask the team assigning the ticket to your team to add the label. Then you can write a JQL to filter all assigned tickets to your team that aren't resolved. If this is the intention I can provide you with an answer. Example : `labels = "Team A" AND status in not (Resolved)`